# Making a function that chains onto querySelector

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to rewrite this jQuery function without the jQuery.

```
jQuery.fn.inputError = function(text) {

    $(this).parent('label').addClass('error').find('.title').after("<span class='text'>" + text + "</span>");

};
```

So

```
$('.foo').inputError('message');
```

Becomes

```
document.querySelector('.foo').inputError('message');
```

Problem is I'm not entirely sure how to write a function so that is can be chained onto a `querySelector()`.

For personal preference **I don't want to be doing**:

```
inputError(document.querySelector('foo'));
```

How may I write a custom function so that it may be chained onto a querySelector?

--

EDIT. Working solution:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.inputError = function(text) {

  var label = this.parentNode,
      error = document.createElement("span");

  error.innerHTML = text;

  label.classList.add('test');
  label.insertBefore(error, label.firstChild);

};
```

Comment: Hint: that function should be a property of whatever `document.querySelector()` returns.

Comment: You either need to extend Node/Nodelist or write a wrapper to encapsulate Node/Nodelist to give a builder-pattern effect. In-short you may end up doing what jquery is doing :). So why not use it at first place?

Comment: This might interest you
http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/creating-chainable-interfaces-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On modern browsers (and IE8), you can extend the prototype of `HTMLElement` by adding functions:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.inputError = function(msg) {
    // `this` is the element, so perhaps:
    this.innerHTML = msg;
};
```

Example:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.inputError = function(msg) {
  // `this` is the element, so perhaps:
  this.innerHTML = msg;
};

document.querySelector(".foo").inputError("Hi there");
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
```

The problem with doing that is that if everyone did it, you'd run into conflicts with different scripts trying to redefine the same methods on elements. And/or when new standard methods are added, they could happen to have the same names, etc.

This is what PrototypeJS did back in the day (it also allowed for updating individual elements for browsers like IE7 and earlier that didn't support `HTMLElement.prototype`).

The other approach is to do what jQuery does and create your own wrapper object. jQuery did that and simultaneously took a set-based approach rather than an element-based approach, which has been phenomenally successful.